# Error while loading shared library python from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

im getting this error on my windows 10 machine. Im using gitbash, does anyone know why this is appearing? I've checked the PATH variable and the executable location is listed there. I recently moved hardrive from a different pc to this one. Python was working fine on the previous pc, but not this one. Any ideas? Its missing some shared library files, but exactly which ones im not so sure.

```
$ python
C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You'd probably have a better time just reinstalling Python.

Comment: Clean install fixed it#